# How do I connect a dataGrid to a DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, wpfdatagrid

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Telephone_Directory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            telephone2010DataSet dataSet = new telephone2010DataSet();

            telephone2010DataSetTableAdapter adapter = 
                new telephone2010DataSetTableAdapter();
        }
    }
}
```

The above is my code is a new project. Visual Studio 2010 complains that " the type or namespace 'telephone2010DataSetTableAdapter' could not be found."

I created a new solution. I right clicked the solution name and selected "Add Existing Item" and located my Microsoft Access DB file. I followed the wizard and it setup the necessary XSD files.

I started coding and I got this message. I did a little google-ing and I cant figure it out.

This is a WPF application created with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

If you used VS.NET to create the typed data sets (btw, you might want to take a look at LINQ-to-Entities, as it's a better model), you should see another namespace under the `Telephone_Directory` namespace which contains the typed data sets/adapters/etc.

Additionally, in VS.NET, you can always right-click on the `teleophone2010DataSet` type name and select "Resolve" which will then place the using statement at the top of the code file or use the namespace-qualified type name where appropriate (it's your choice) if the type is unresolved.

Comment: Well I am aware of the "Right click" and resolve but in my case, the telephone2010DataSetTableAdapter doesn't have the Contextual Menu for resolve.